# removing href value on logo for purchase/checkout flow

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, header

Is it a common best practice to the remove the href value of the header logo in a checkout / trial registration flow?

The upside is to reduce exit links, keeping the user on your checkout page and forcing them to use their browser back button to get back to your site.

The downside is it's frustrating if you're the user trying to back out.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but highly related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/is-it-user-friendly-to-make-the-main-navigation-bar-disappear-when-the-user-proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of it. That would be an indicator of a broken site. Which in turn means bad quality, which in turn is suspicious. Normal user would just close the tab/window and never return to your web site. If you cannot provide a normal web site, how can anyone expect that you are capable to securely process  payments, that you are capable to deliver the products.

Comment: Reducing links (including internal) during the checkout process is very common practice.